# HP Network Device Management Software

Tags: networking, hp, snmp, network-monitoring, stp

I look after a network with 11 x new HP v1910 24-port 1GB switches and 2 x HP 4204vl 1GB Chassis switches. I'm looking for software to enable me to:

1. Map the network graphically - there are a lot of fibre and copper LACP links
2. Provide a single view of the state of the network - I'd like to see the current MSTP trees
3. Enable the devices to be managed from a single interface, as 13 separate tabs in the browser plus telnet logins is a pest
4. Monitor and record sFlow and RMON data for historic purposes
5. provide alerts for e.g. LACP state change or MSTP reconfiguration

We have Microsoft System Center Essentials 2010, but I can't seem to get a single network diagram with it. I've looked on here: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html but I drowned in excess choice.

Windows-based solutions strongly preferred. Free solutions ideal, but not essential.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the kind of thing which you may need to have several different packages, each specializing in one thing.  NMS software doesn't always do everything well.  What about something like http://www.solarwinds.com/ ?  http://www.nagios.org/ may also fulfill some of your needs.